# Error when trying to instantiate class in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Using VS 2017 and Xamarin.Forms, has anyone seen an error like this?

**{Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException}    Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException
Didn't find class "md546f3e293680064826a8f4de8cb5b1ad9.ZebraTC75" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]**

In the output pane, I get the following:

**09-30 10:39:44.712 I/art ( 9673): Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class md546f3e293680064826a8f4de8cb5b1ad9.ZebraTC75**

I have multi-dex off. seems ZebraTC75 class could not be found. Am I missing a setting to include?

This class is in my Android project.

This class also is inherited from a "Base" class.

The error appears in debug mode when i step into the constructor of the "base" class.

Thanks,
Austin

Comment: The only thing I can find about Zebra TC75 is a mobile scanner. Are you using that device? The part before could be an MD5 hash. Can you find a .class file with this name anywhere on your computer?

Comment: Yes. This is an internal class we created to use the symbol xamarin dll's. Yes, the ZebraTC75.cs is included in the project.       
    <Compile Include="Hardware\Scanners\ZebraTC75.cs" />

Comment: When I step through the code, i have a breakpoint set in the constructor of my ZebraTC75.cs. It will stop at the break point, and i can step into :base () which will step into the "Base" constructor. As soon as I step into the "Base" constructor, I get the exception.